# GCM - where is a catch?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

GCM seems to be too good to be free.
I mean, there are messaging/notification functionality, XMPP functionality etc. And it all requires internet bandwidth / server capacity / storage etc..
Moreover, even iOS platforms can use the GCM ( XMPP ) and it's all for free.

It seems a bit weird for me, so I try to find a catch ( especially, taking into account, that there are some similar paid services in the internet ).
Did anyone try to create a big setup ( with lots of clients ) on GCM/XMPP?
Did you succeed? Or maybe there is somewhere a limit/threshold and you have to pay if you reach it?

Any advice/considerations would be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Best Regards,
Maksim

Answer (score 1):

No catch, [GCM is a free service](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm) to developers. Many large applications use GCM to deliver messages.

Comment: But what about XMPP stuff?